# Android seekBar change color on value change

Tags: android

I'm using [discreteSeekBar](https://github.com/AnderWeb/discreteSeekBar).
Does anyone know how to change indicator color while scrolling?

When i use:

```
 class SeekBarOnProgressChangeListener implements DiscreteSeekBar.OnProgressChangeListener {
    int color;

    public Trap5SeekBarOnProgressChangeListener() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
        seekBar.setIndicatorPopupEnabled(false);

        if(value == 0) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarGreen);
        } else if(value < 20) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarGreen);
        } else if(value < 40) {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarYellow);
        } else {
            color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarRed);
        }

        seekBar.setScrubberColor(color);
        seekBar.setThumbColor(color, color);
    }
```

}

The color changes since next use of seekBar, not as i want instantly.
Proof: https://s3.postimg.org/to93ovej7/proof.png

Comment: It is better to apply color in onStopTrackingTouch() method.

Comment: my goal is to change the color while user is sliding, for ex. if user goes above value 40 the whole seekBar turns red, so changing the color in onStopTrackingTouch() is not a good way ;/

Comment: You set the color in onprogresschanged() method. And Apply it in onStopTrackingTouch() method

Comment: You guys dont understand my intentions, i want the color to be changed while user is using my snackBar, not after he is done, and my code (the one above) works fine for changing the scrubber color but the thumb new color is applied since next use of seekBar, not as i want instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded at achieving my goal, this is the solution:

```
class SeekBarOnProgressChangeListener implements DiscreteSeekBar.OnProgressChangeListener {
    int color;
    int colorGreen;
    int colorYellow;
    int colorRed;

    public SeekBarOnProgressChangeListener() {
        colorGreen = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarGreen);
        colorYellow = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarYellow);
        colorRed= ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarRed);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(DiscreteSeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
        boolean colorChanged = false;

        if(value < 20) {
            if(color != colorGreen){
                color = colorGreen;
                colorChanged = true;
            }
        } else if(value < 40) {
            if(color != colorYellow){
                color = colorYellow;
                colorChanged = true;
            }
        } else {
            if(color != colorRed){
                color = colorRed;
                colorChanged = true;
            }

        }

        if(colorChanged) {
            seekBar.setScrubberColor(color);
            seekBar.setThumbColor(color, color);

            MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(System.currentTimeMillis(), System.currentTimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, 0, 0, 0);
            seekBar.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
        }

    }
```

The thumb reappears in a changed color when new color is set, it is good enough for me, but if anyone has a solution that changes thumb color without recreating it, please post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

```
@Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int value, boolean fromUser) {
                if(value == 0) {
                    color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarGreen);
                } else if(value < 20) {
                    color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarGreen);
                } else if(value < 40) {
                    color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarYellow);
                } else {
                    color = ContextCompat.getColor(seekBar.getContext(), R.color.colorSneekBarRed);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekBar.setScrubberColor(color);
                seekBar.setThumbColor(color, color);
            }
```